# Can I replace the OpenLayers editing toolbar with normal buttons?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

This little [`OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/EditingToolbar-js.html) from is inserted by default:

[image]

It's not really evident what these buttons mean. I would like to replace this editing toolbar with a button group (e.g. like the one Twitter Bootstrap offers):

[image]

The markup of the editing toolbar currently is this:

```
<div id="panel" class="olControlEditingToolbar">
  <div class="olControlNavigationItemInactive olButton"></div>
  <div class="olControlDrawFeaturePointItemActive olButton"></div>
  <div class="olControlDrawFeaturePathItemInactive olButton"></div>
  <div class="olControlDrawFeaturePolygonItemInactive olButton"></div>
</div>
```

The images are basic sprites – so I know I could change these. But I can't see how I could get away from these `div`s, replacing them with `button`s. I thought about just creating the button group manually and add `click()` event listeners to the buttons, triggering OpenLayers' different editing modes. But I couldn't find any documentation on how I could do that.

---

So, basically, I see these options:

- Create button group manually, and trigger the appropriate OpenLayers events through my own JS — but which events do I need to trigger?
- Don't use the `EditingToolbar`, but manually build my toolbar with OpenLayers — how could I do  that?
- Modify the automatically created editing toolbar by hacking the OpenLayers source *(meh…)* — is this worth the effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to manually build the control buttons. Based on the [Draw Feature Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html), you can go ahead and add your controls:

```
drawControls = {
  point: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(pointLayer,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
  line: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(lineLayer,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Path),
  polygon: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer,
      OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
  )
};

for(var key in drawControls) {
  map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
}
```

Then, add a function that changes the currently used control based on a clicked element:

```
function toggleControl(element) {
    for(key in drawControls) {
        var control = drawControls[key];
        if(element.value == key && element.checked) {
            control.activate();
        } else {
            control.deactivate();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, create the HTML markup yourself. For each element that changes the control, add an `onClick` handler that calls the `toggleControl` function. You can also attach the click handler through jQuery, but in essence, this works:

```
<ul id="controlToggle">
  <li>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="none" id="noneToggle"
             onclick="toggleControl(this);" checked="checked" />
      <label for="noneToggle">navigate</label>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" onclick="toggleControl(this);" />
      <label for="pointToggle">draw point</label>
  </li>
  <!-- add more elements here, based on which draw modes you added -->
</ul>
```

You can see this [in action here](http://maphub.herokuapp.com/) (sign up with a test user, no real e-mail needed) and find the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/maphub/maphub-portal/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/maps/annotation_view.js.erb).